Problem opening my React Native App on emulator and Phone
I am trying to open a newly created React Native project created with "Expo CLI" in Windows 11 using VS Code. My device is on same WIFI as my laptop. But I keep getting the following error on my device:

Uncaught Error: java.io.IOException: Unexception end of stream on http://192.168.234.5:8081/...

In an attempt to clear it, I used npx expo start --tunnel and it is giving a different error:

Uncaught Error: Java.lang.Exception: ngrok gateway error. The server returned an invalid or incomplete HTTP response ERR_NGROK_3004

I tried opening a newly created Expo project on both an emulator and a physical phone. I expected the default expo app to open on the emulator or the phone. But I am getting errors.  The phone has USB debugging enabled.

What is the Android version and your device make, model? Is it possible to test with USB cable connection?
